# Eliminating fractions in an array

Tags: simplifying-expressions, list-manipulation

I have an array in which every element is a fraction (some are real , some are a sum of real + complex part). I want to find the smallest common denominator in order to obtain a factor * array containing only integer numbers (real and complex).

Any ideas?

An example array:

```
A = {1/24 + 7i/32, 83/25, 4/78 + 9i/17...}
```

Answer (score 4):

How about (with `i` changed to a proper imaginary unit: `I`)

```
A = {1/24 + 7 I/32, 83/25, 4/78 + 9 I/17};

den = Denominator[A]
```

> {96, 25, 663}

```
lcm = LCM @@ den
```

> 530400

```
A*lcm // Expand
```

> {22100 + 116025 I, 1760928, 27200 + 280800 I}

---

Indeed, `lcm` is smaller than `Times @@ den == 1591200`.

Comment: `Denominator[A]` is enough with `I` instead of `i`.

Comment: Ha! That's what you get blindly assuming that the OP's input is correct ;)

Comment: You could also use `GCD @@ A`

Answer (score 0):

In:

```
A = {1/24 + 7 I/32, 83/25, 4/78 + 9 I/17};
Denominator[Plus @@ A] A
```

Out:

```
{22100 + 116025 I, 1760928, 27200 + 280800 I}
```

Comment: Consider an array like {1/2,1/2}